# Where was my data stored? Python Intelligence

Tags: python-2.7

I need some help to interpret the following codes.

In the book, the author provided an `advancedclassify.py` script to read the CSV file in python

```
class matchrow:
   def __init__(self,row,allnum=False):
   if allnum:
      self.data=[float(row[i]) for i in range(len(row)-1)]
   else:
      self.data=row[0:len(row)-1]
   self.match=int(row[len(row)-1])

def loadmatch(f,allnum=False):
   rows=[]
   for line in file(f):
       rows.append(matchrow(line.split(','),allnum))
   return rows
```

If now I read a file called `matchmake.csv`:

```
import advancedclassify
matchmaker = advancedclassify.loadmatch('matchmaker.csv')
print(matchmaker)
```

But matchmaker did not store my data. I do not know where my data stored.

The csv file each line is simply like this:

```
39,yes,no,skiing:knitting:dancing,220 W 42nd St New NY
43,no,yes,soccer:reading:scrabble,824 3rd Ave New York NY,0
```

I will very appreciate someone can help me and it was struggling me since I am new to python. Thanks.

Source: Programming Collective Intelligence Ch9

Comment: This is probably related to you screwing up your indentation.

Comment: No, that is not true. It is not my code. It is code from a book  and I can use the code to do the tasks later.

Comment: What do you mean with "did not store my data"? What's the output from `print(matchmaker)`?

Comment: Rows following `def __init__(self,row,allnum=False):` should be indented. That is probably your original problem, but it is wrong. You should edit  your question to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from [here](https://github.com/cataska/programming-collective-intelligence-code/tree/master/chapter9), this:

```
import advancedclassify
matchmaker = advancedclassify.loadmatch('matchmaker.csv')
print(matchmaker[:2])
```

prints:

```
[<advancedclassify.matchrow instance at 0x1005e3a28>, <advancedclassify.matchrow instance at 0x1005e33f8>]
```

So `matchmaker` is a list of `matchrow` instances. That's your data.

The actual data is stored in the `match`attribute of the instance. Have a look with:

```
for match in matchmaker:
    print(match.data)
```

Comment: So, how can I call my data?

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.